# Layer has 2 states but was passed 1 initial states error occurs while using Keras 2.9.0 for implementing multiplicative LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to adapt the code for multiplicative LSTM code on [github](https://github.com/nfrn/Multi-Modal-Classification-of-Radiology-Exams/blob/master/Text_Models/BioBERT/multiplicative_lstm.py) to use the latest version of Keras 2.9.0.The code is :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import numpy as np
__all__ = ['MultiplicativeLSTM']
from keras import backend as K
from keras import activations
from keras import initializers
from keras import regularizers
from keras import constraints
from keras.engine import Layer
from keras.engine import InputSpec
from keras.legacy import interfaces
from keras.layers import Recurrent
class MultiplicativeLSTM(Recurrent):
    """Multiplicative Long-Short Term Memory unit - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.07959.pdf
    """
    @interfaces.legacy_recurrent_support
    def __init__(self, units,
                 activation='tanh',
                 recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 unit_forget_bias=True,
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 recurrent_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 recurrent_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 dropout=0.,
                 recurrent_dropout=0.,
                 implementation=1,
                 **kwargs):
        super(MultiplicativeLSTM, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.recurrent_activation = activations.get(recurrent_activation)
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.recurrent_initializer = initializers.get(recurrent_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
        self.unit_forget_bias = unit_forget_bias
        self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
        self.recurrent_regularizer = regularizers.get(recurrent_regularizer)
        self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
        self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)
        self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
        self.recurrent_constraint = constraints.get(recurrent_constraint)
        self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)
        self.dropout = min(1., max(0., dropout))
        self.recurrent_dropout = min(1., max(0., recurrent_dropout))
        self.state_spec = [InputSpec(shape=(None, self.units)),
                           InputSpec(shape=(None, self.units))]
        self.state_size = (self.units, self.units)
        self.implementation = implementation
    def build(self, input_shape):
        if isinstance(input_shape, list):
            input_shape = input_shape[0]
        batch_size = input_shape[0] if self.stateful else None
        self.input_dim = input_shape[2]
        self.input_spec[0] = InputSpec(shape=(batch_size, None, self.input_dim))
        self.states = [None, None]
        if self.stateful:
            self.reset_states()
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(self.input_dim, self.units * 5),
                                      name='kernel',
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units * 5),
            name='recurrent_kernel',
            initializer=self.recurrent_initializer,
            regularizer=self.recurrent_regularizer,
            constraint=self.recurrent_constraint)
        if self.use_bias:
            if self.unit_forget_bias:
                def bias_initializer(shape, *args, **kwargs):
                    return K.concatenate([
                        self.bias_initializer((self.units,), *args, **kwargs),
                        initializers.Ones()((self.units,), *args, **kwargs),
                        self.bias_initializer((self.units * 3,), *args, **kwargs),
                    ])
            else:
                bias_initializer = self.bias_initializer
            self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units * 5,),
                                        name='bias',
                                        initializer=bias_initializer,
                                        regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                        constraint=self.bias_constraint)
        else:
            self.bias = None
        self.kernel_i = self.kernel[:, :self.units]
        self.kernel_f = self.kernel[:, self.units: self.units * 2]
        self.kernel_c = self.kernel[:, self.units * 2: self.units * 3]
        self.kernel_o = self.kernel[:, self.units * 3: self.units * 4]
        self.kernel_m = self.kernel[:, self.units * 4:]
        self.recurrent_kernel_i = self.recurrent_kernel[:, :self.units]
        self.recurrent_kernel_f = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units: self.units * 2]
        self.recurrent_kernel_c = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 2: self.units * 3]
        self.recurrent_kernel_o = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 3: self.units * 4]
        self.recurrent_kernel_m = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 4:]
        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias_i = self.bias[:self.units]
            self.bias_f = self.bias[self.units: self.units * 2]
            self.bias_c = self.bias[self.units * 2: self.units * 3]
            self.bias_o = self.bias[self.units * 3: self.units * 4]
            self.bias_m = self.bias[self.units * 4:]
        else:
            self.bias_i = None
            self.bias_f = None
            self.bias_c = None
            self.bias_o = None
            self.bias_m = None
        self.built = True
    def preprocess_input(self, inputs, training=None):
        return inputs
    def get_constants(self, inputs, training=None):
        constants = []
        if self.implementation != 0 and 0 < self.dropout < 1:
            input_shape = K.int_shape(inputs)
            input_dim = input_shape[-1]
            ones = K.ones_like(K.reshape(inputs[:, 0, 0], (-1, 1)))
            ones = K.tile(ones, (1, int(input_dim)))
            def dropped_inputs():
                return K.dropout(ones, self.dropout)
            dp_mask = [K.in_train_phase(dropped_inputs,
                                        ones,
                                        training=training) for _ in range(5)]
            constants.append(dp_mask)
        else:
            constants.append([K.cast_to_floatx(1.) for _ in range(5)])
        if 0 < self.recurrent_dropout < 1:
            ones = K.ones_like(K.reshape(inputs[:, 0, 0], (-1, 1)))
            ones = K.tile(ones, (1, self.units))
            def dropped_inputs():
                return K.dropout(ones, self.recurrent_dropout)
            rec_dp_mask = [K.in_train_phase(dropped_inputs,
                                            ones,
                                            training=training) for _ in range(5)]
            constants.append(rec_dp_mask)
        else:
            constants.append([K.cast_to_floatx(1.) for _ in range(5)])
        return constants
    def step(self, inputs, states):
        h_tm1 = states[0]
        c_tm1 = states[1]
        dp_mask = states[2]
        rec_dp_mask = states[3]
        if self.implementation == 2:
            z = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[0], self.kernel)
            z += z * K.dot(h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[0], self.recurrent_kernel) # applies m instead of h_tm1 to z
            if self.use_bias:
                z = K.bias_add(z, self.bias)
            z0 = z[:, :self.units]
            z1 = z[:, self.units: 2 * self.units]
            z2 = z[:, 2 * self.units: 3 * self.units]
            z3 = z[:, 3 * self.units: 4 * self.units]
            z4 = z[:, 4 * self.units:] # just elementwise multiplication, no activation functions
            i = self.recurrent_activation(z0)
            f = self.recurrent_activation(z1)
            c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(z2)
            o = self.recurrent_activation(z3)
        else:
            if self.implementation == 1:
                x_i = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[0], self.kernel_i) + self.bias_i
                x_f = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[1], self.kernel_f) + self.bias_f
                x_c = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[2], self.kernel_c) + self.bias_c
                x_o = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[3], self.kernel_o) + self.bias_o
                x_m = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[4], self.kernel_m) + self.bias_m
            else:
                raise ValueError('Unknown `implementation` mode.')
            m = x_m * K.dot(h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[4], self.recurrent_kernel_m) # elementwise multiplication m
            i = self.recurrent_activation(x_i + K.dot(m * rec_dp_mask[0], self.recurrent_kernel_i))
            f = self.recurrent_activation(x_f + K.dot(m * rec_dp_mask[1], self.recurrent_kernel_f))
            c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + K.dot(m * rec_dp_mask[2], self.recurrent_kernel_c))
            o = self.recurrent_activation(x_o + K.dot(m * rec_dp_mask[3], self.recurrent_kernel_o))
        h = o * self.activation(c)
        if 0 < self.dropout + self.recurrent_dropout:
            h._uses_learning_phase = True
        return h, [h, c]
    def get_config(self):
        config = {'units': self.units,
                  'activation': activations.serialize(self.activation),
                  'recurrent_activation': activations.serialize(self.recurrent_activation),
                  'use_bias': self.use_bias,
                  'kernel_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.kernel_initializer),
                  'recurrent_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.recurrent_initializer),
                  'bias_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.bias_initializer),
                  'unit_forget_bias': self.unit_forget_bias,
                  'kernel_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.kernel_regularizer),
                  'recurrent_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.recurrent_regularizer),
                  'bias_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.bias_regularizer),
                  'activity_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.activity_regularizer),
                  'kernel_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.kernel_constraint),
                  'recurrent_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.recurrent_constraint),
                  'bias_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.bias_constraint),
                  'dropout': self.dropout,
                  'recurrent_dropout': self.recurrent_dropout}
        base_config = super(MultiplicativeLSTM, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

As mentioned, I am using the latest version of Keras, and have tried to use keras.layers.RNN instead of the old class Recurrent, removed use of interfaces and the corresponding annotations. As the new RNN requires a cell, I have added that variable also in the class for MultiplicativeLSTM. The code that uses this class, passes SimpleRNNCell for cell. The modified code is below.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import numpy as np
__all__ = ['MultiplicativeLSTM']
import keras.backend as K
from keras import activations
from keras import initializers
from keras import regularizers
from keras import constraints
from keras.layers import InputSpec
from keras.layers import RNN, LSTM, SimpleRNNCell, LSTMV2, LSTMCellV2
import keras
from keras.layers import Layer
class MultiplicativeLSTM(RNN):
    """Multiplicative Long-Short Term Memory unit - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.07959.pdf
    # Arguments
        units: Positive integer, dimensionality of the output space.
        activation: Activation function to use
            (see [activations](../activations.md)).
            If you pass None, no activation is applied
            (ie. "linear" activation: `a(x) = x`).
        recurrent_activation: Activation function to use
            for the recurrent step
            (see [activations](../activations.md)).
        use_bias: Boolean, whether the layer uses a bias vector.
    # References
        - [Long short-term memory](http://www.bioinf.jku.at/publications/older/2604.pdf) (original 1997 paper)
        - [Learning to forget: Continual prediction with MultiplicativeLSTM](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/089976600300015015)
        - [Supervised sequence labeling with recurrent neural networks](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/preprint.pdf)
        - [A Theoretically Grounded Application of Dropout in Recurrent Neural Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05287)
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 cell,
                 units,
                 activation='tanh',
                 recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 unit_forget_bias=True,
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 recurrent_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 recurrent_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 dropout=0.,
                 recurrent_dropout=0.,
                 implementation=1,
                 **kwargs):
        super(MultiplicativeLSTM, self).__init__(cell=cell, **kwargs)
        self.cell = cell
        self.units = units
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.recurrent_activation = activations.get(recurrent_activation)
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.recurrent_initializer = initializers.get(recurrent_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
        self.unit_forget_bias = unit_forget_bias
        self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
        self.recurrent_regularizer = regularizers.get(recurrent_regularizer)
        self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
        self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)
        self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
        self.recurrent_constraint = constraints.get(recurrent_constraint)
        self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)
        self.dropout = min(1., max(0., dropout))
        self.recurrent_dropout = min(1., max(0., recurrent_dropout))
        self.state_spec = [InputSpec(shape=(None, self.units)),
                           InputSpec(shape=(None, self.units))]
        self.state_size = (self.units, self.units)
        self.implementation = implementation
    def build(self, input_shape):
        if isinstance(input_shape, list):
            input_shape = input_shape[0]
        batch_size = input_shape[0] if self.stateful else None
        self.input_dim = input_shape[2]
        self.input_spec = [None]
        self.input_spec[0] = InputSpec(shape=(batch_size, None, self.input_dim))
        self.states = [None, None]
        if self.stateful:
            self.reset_states()
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(self.input_dim, self.units * 5),
                                      name='kernel',
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units * 5),
            name='recurrent_kernel',
            initializer=self.recurrent_initializer,
            regularizer=self.recurrent_regularizer,
            constraint=self.recurrent_constraint)
        if self.use_bias:
            if self.unit_forget_bias:
                def bias_initializer(shape, *args, **kwargs):
                    return K.concatenate([
                        self.bias_initializer((self.units,), *args, **kwargs),
                        initializers.Ones()((self.units,), *args, **kwargs),
                        self.bias_initializer((self.units * 3,), *args, **kwargs),
                    ])
            else:
                bias_initializer = self.bias_initializer
            self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units * 5,),
                                        name='bias',
                                        initializer=bias_initializer,
                                        regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                        constraint=self.bias_constraint)
        else:
            self.bias = None
        self.kernel_i = self.kernel[:, :self.units]
        self.kernel_f = self.kernel[:, self.units: self.units * 2]
        self.kernel_c = self.kernel[:, self.units * 2: self.units * 3]
        self.kernel_o = self.kernel[:, self.units * 3: self.units * 4]
        self.kernel_m = self.kernel[:, self.units * 4:]
        self.recurrent_kernel_i = self.recurrent_kernel[:, :self.units]
        self.recurrent_kernel_f = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units: self.units * 2]
        self.recurrent_kernel_c = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 2: self.units * 3]
        self.recurrent_kernel_o = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 3: self.units * 4]
        self.recurrent_kernel_m = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 4:]
        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias_i = self.bias[:self.units]
            self.bias_f = self.bias[self.units: self.units * 2]
            self.bias_c = self.bias[self.units * 2: self.units * 3]
            self.bias_o = self.bias[self.units * 3: self.units * 4]
            self.bias_m = self.bias[self.units * 4:]
        else:
            self.bias_i = None
            self.bias_f = None
            self.bias_c = None
            self.bias_o = None
            self.bias_m = None
        self.built = True
    def preprocess_input(self, inputs, training=None):
        return inputs
    def get_constants(self, inputs, training=None):
        constants = []
        if self.implementation != 0 and 0 < self.dropout < 1:
            input_shape = K.int_shape(inputs)
            input_dim = input_shape[-1]
            ones = K.ones_like(K.reshape(inputs[:, 0, 0], (-1, 1)))
            ones = K.tile(ones, (1, int(input_dim)))
            def dropped_inputs():
                return K.dropout(ones, self.dropout)
            dp_mask = [K.in_train_phase(dropped_inputs,
                                        ones,
                                        training=training) for _ in range(5)]
            constants.append(dp_mask)
        else:
            constants.append([K.cast_to_floatx(1.) for _ in range(5)])
        if 0 < self.recurrent_dropout < 1:
            ones = K.ones_like(K.reshape(inputs[:, 0, 0], (-1, 1)))
            ones = K.tile(ones, (1, self.units))
            def dropped_inputs():
                return K.dropout(ones, self.recurrent_dropout)
            rec_dp_mask = [K.in_train_phase(dropped_inputs,
                                            ones,
                                            training=training) for _ in range(5)]
            constants.append(rec_dp_mask)
        else:
            constants.append([K.cast_to_floatx(1.) for _ in range(5)])
        return constants
    def step(self, inputs, states):
        h_tm1 = states[0]
        c_tm1 = states[1]
        dp_mask = states[2]
        rec_dp_mask = states[3]
        if self.implementation == 2:
            z = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[0], self.kernel)
            z += z * K.dot(h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[0], self.recurrent_kernel)  # applies m instead of h_tm1 to z
            if self.use_bias:
                z = K.bias_add(z, self.bias)
            z0 = z[:, :self.units]
            z1 = z[:, self.units: 2 * self.units]
            z2 = z[:, 2 * self.units: 3 * self.units]
            z3 = z[:, 3 * self.units: 4 * self.units]
            z4 = z[:, 4 * self.units:]  # just elementwise multiplication, no activation functions
            i = self.recurrent_activation(z0)
            f = self.recurrent_activation(z1)
            c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(z2)
            o = self.recurrent_activation(z3)
        else:
            if self.implementation == 1:
                x_i = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[0], self.kernel_i) + self.bias_i
                x_f = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[1], self.kernel_f) + self.bias_f
                x_c = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[2], self.kernel_c) + self.bias_c
                x_o = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[3], self.kernel_o) + self.bias_o
                x_m = K.dot(inputs * dp_mask[4], self.kernel_m) + self.bias_m
            else:
                raise ValueError('Unknown `implementation` mode.')
            m = x_m * K.dot(h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[4], self.recurrent_kernel_m)  # elementwise multiplication m
            i = self.recurrent_activation(x_i + K.dot(m * rec_dp_mask[0], self.recurrent_kernel_i))
            f = self.recurrent_activation(x_f + K.dot(m * rec_dp_mask[1], self.recurrent_kernel_f))
            c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + K.dot(m * rec_dp_mask[2], self.recurrent_kernel_c))
            o = self.recurrent_activation(x_o + K.dot(m * rec_dp_mask[3], self.recurrent_kernel_o))
        h = o * self.activation(c)
        if 0 < self.dropout + self.recurrent_dropout:
            h._uses_learning_phase = True
        return h, [h, c]
    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'units': self.units,
                  'activation': activations.serialize(self.activation),
                  'recurrent_activation': activations.serialize(self.recurrent_activation),
                  'use_bias': self.use_bias,
                  'kernel_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.kernel_initializer),
                  'recurrent_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.recurrent_initializer),
                  'bias_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.bias_initializer),
                  'unit_forget_bias': self.unit_forget_bias,
                  'kernel_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.kernel_regularizer),
                  'recurrent_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.recurrent_regularizer),
                  'bias_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.bias_regularizer),
                  'activity_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.activity_regularizer),
                  'kernel_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.kernel_constraint),
                  'recurrent_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.recurrent_constraint),
                  'bias_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.bias_constraint),
                  'dropout': self.dropout,
                  'recurrent_dropout': self.recurrent_dropout}
        base_config = super(MultiplicativeLSTM, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

The code that calls the MultiplicativeLSTM is in loadModel() method,

```
import codecs
import pickle
import keras
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import Input, Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras.metrics import AUC
from keras.layers import Layer, Bidirectional, Embedding, Dense, Flatten
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
from keras_multi_head import MultiHeadAttention
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from metrics import roc_callback, \
    auc_roc
from multiplicative_lstm import MultiplicativeLSTM
from keras.layers import SimpleRNNCell, LSTMCell, LSTMCellV2
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint, Tokenizer
from CiclicLR import CyclicLR
from datagenerator import DataGenerator
import os
MAX_WORDS_TEXT = 500
WORD_EMBEDDINGS_SIZE = 200
EPOCHS = 30
BATCH_SIZE = 64
TRAIN = "../../Datasets/MIMIC-III/train.csv"
TEST = "../../Datasets/MIMIC-III/test.csv"
VAL = "../../Datasets/MIMIC-III/val.csv"
def loadModel():
    input = Input((500, 3072))
    mlstm_layer = MultiplicativeLSTM(
            cell=SimpleRNNCell(14),
            units=256,
            return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2,
            recurrent_dropout=0.2
        )
    rnn_layer = Bidirectional(
        mlstm_layer,
        merge_mode='concat')(input)
    attention_layer = MultiHeadAttention(head_num=4)(rnn_layer)
    removeMask = Flatten()(attention_layer)
    final = Dense(14, activation='sigmoid')(removeMask)
    model_complete = Model(inputs=input, outputs=final)
    model_complete.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
                           metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model_complete.summary())
    return model_complete
def train(model):
    dataGen = DataGenerator("train", 169728, BATCH_SIZE, True)
    dataGenval = DataGenerator("val", 42432, BATCH_SIZE, False)
    dataGentest = DataGenerator("test", 48832, 64, False)
    filepath = "Model-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"
    modelckp = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=False,
                               mode='min')
    callbacks_list = [modelckp]
    model.fit_generator(dataGen,
                        callbacks=callbacks_list,
                        validation_data=dataGenval,
                        use_multiprocessing=False,
                        verbose=1,
                        epochs=EPOCHS
                        workers=4)
    model.save_weights("Model.h5")
```

When I run the latest version of the classes, I get the below exception,

```cs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Model.py", line 284, in <module>
    model = loadModel()
  File "/Model.py", line 192, in loadModel
    rnn_layer = Bidirectional(
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/rnn/bidirectional.py", line 249, in __call__
    return super(Bidirectional, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/rnn/base_rnn.py", line 728, in _process_inputs
    raise ValueError(f'Layer has {len(self.states)} '
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "forward_multiplicative_lstm" (type MultiplicativeLSTM).
Layer has 2 states but was passed 1 initial states. Received: initial_state=[<tf.Tensor 'bidirectional/forward_multiplicative_lstm/zeros:0' shape=(None, 14) dtype=float32>]
Call arguments received by layer "forward_multiplicative_lstm" (type MultiplicativeLSTM):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 500, 3072), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=None
  • initial_state=None
  • constants=None
```

I am not sure if it is about the shape that is causing the issue. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Latha

Comment: Does your code run if your remove the BiDirectional wrapper around your custom LSTM layer? I'm just curious while trying to understand what might happen.

Comment: @Nilau: No, it does not run. I get the same error, except that the stack trace now specifies to RNN rather than Bidirectional. 

 File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/rnn/base_rnn.py", line 515, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).